# pymongo import errors in python3 flask application

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a python `flask` based app, which writes to mongo database.

I am using `python 3` with the following `requirements.txt`

```
Flask
Jinja2
Werkzeug
certifi
chardet
gunicorn
requests
flask_restful
flask
pymongo
```

I run into this issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/app.py", line 4, in <module>
from helper import save_message_2_db
File "/app/bin/helper.py", line 1, in <module>
from database import DataAccess, MongoDB
File "/app/bin/database.py", line 1, in <module>
import pymongo
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 21, in <module>
from bson.code import Code
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/code.py", line 19, in <module>
from bson.py3compat import string_type, PY3, text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bson.py3compat'
```

I am trying to understand why does this happen?

This section is what I am concerned with

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 21, in <module>
from bson.code import Code
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/code.py", line 19, in <module>
from bson.py3compat import string_type, PY3, text_type
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bson.py3compat'
```

Most of the internet blogs/links tell me `bson` and `pymongo` dont play well with eachother. `pymongo` has its own version of `bson` and i dont need it in my `requirements.txt`.

I am looking for help to see why this happens, and how to remidiate this.

---

Update #1

I was using `pymongo-3.5.1`, and thats where the problem persists. I just downgraded to `pymongo-3.5.0` and the problem vanished.

This means I know the workaround to fix this, but the upstream code/package has some issues which needs fixing.

Comment: I believe the above error is something to do with my `python version` and `requirements.txt`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading again? A [comparison](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/compare/0b0f045...ca57ece) between those two versions does not show relevant changes to your issue.

Comment: @c11o - this is crazy, i guess i had a issue of some sort in my heroku deploy procedure. now i moved to latest, and I dont see that problem.

Comment: still driving me crazy, why did this happen? the buildpacks on heroku destroy the virtualenv and resurrect it everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be some package misconfiguration going on. If the bson package is from
the [mongo-python-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/tree/master/bson), which is likely, since in line 19, the import statement `from bson.py3compat import string_type, PY3, text_type` is present.

However the file `py3compat.py` seems to be missing, which should be right next to `code.py` in the `bson` path.

**Update**

After the question's update letting us know a downgrade fixed the issue and inspecting the [code changes](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/compare/0b0f045...ca57ece) between both versions, no relevant changes to the issue are identifiable. Therefore it even more so suggests there was something wrong with the modules, what exactly is hard to tell.

Comment: that seems to be the closest answer so far, still a mystery as to why am i hitting this.

Comment: i am updating my findings - with your answers direction.

Comment: can u update your answer, - i can select it as the correct approach to finding the steps to debug this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Try to uninstall both `bson` and `pymongo`:

```
sudo pip uninstall bson
sudo pip uninstall pymongo
```

and then reinstall `pymongo` **using pip**:

```
sudo pip install pymongo
```

Comment: yeahp - already tried this, this is the reason why i posted that in my question and provided my requirements file.

Comment: i am not sure - why this step did not work, what i tried was something like this. looks like this could have been an isuee with heroku

Comment: In my case I had to uninstall with `sudo pip uninstall` and then `sudo uninstall` to clean everything, and then it worked :-)

Answer (score 4):

Uninstall both `bson` and `pymongo`. Then, install `bson` first and `pymongo` second.

Answer (score 1):

[@bauman.space](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3093018/bauman-space) provided the most **informative** and **useful** explanation of this bson/ pymongo import issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441445/flask-app-broken-after-bson-update-in-heroku) thread:

> pymongo>=2.7.1 directive overwrites your bson installation
>
> from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver
>
> Do not install the "bson" package from pypi. PyMongo comes with its own bson package; doing `easy_install bson` or `pip install bson` installs a third-party package that is incompatible with PyMongo.
>
> assuming you really want to use the 3rd party bson, you'll need to
>
> pip uninstall bson (removes the overwritten bson that landed via pymongo package)
>   pip install bson (reinstalls the py-bson package)
>   or you could patch the pymongo install to remove the collections.abc line (evidently you don't really need it?), but messing with production packaged code is questionable.
>
> pymongo module https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/py3compat.py#L22-L25
>
> py-bson module you are trying to use. https://github.com/py-bson/bson/blob/master/bson/py3compat.py#L22-L24

Comment: Update: to use pymongo bson, access it through its `collection` module.