# Flask app broken after bson update in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pymongo, mongoengine, bson

I have a Flask app that uses mongoengine and running on Heroku, init I use the `bson` package and after I updateded it from `0.5.6` to `0.5.7`
I started getting the following error message:

```
[2018-11-23 05:56:43 +0000] [39] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 39)
[2018-11-23 05:56:43 +0000] [40] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/app/slots_tracker_server/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mongoengine import connect
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mongoengine import connection
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymongo import MongoClient, ReadPreference, uri_parser
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 20, in <module>
    from bson.code import Code
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/code.py", line 18, in <module>
    from bson.py3compat import abc, string_type, PY3, text_type
ImportError: cannot import name 'abc'
```

This error appears when I restart my server, after that I don't see errors in the log but I can't access the app.
I'm running the same configuration in Travis-CI but there I don't see any issues.
Any idea on how I can fix it?

This is the output of `pip freeze` in my server:

```
blinker==1.4
bson==0.5.7
CacheControl==0.12.5
cachetools==3.0.0
certifi==2018.10.15
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
dateutils==0.6.6
firebase-admin==2.13.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.7
google-api-core==1.5.2
google-auth==1.6.0
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-firestore==0.30.0
google-cloud-storage==1.13.0
google-resumable-media==0.3.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5
grpcio==1.16.1
gspread==3.0.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
httplib2==0.11.3
idna==2.7
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.0
mongoengine==0.16.1
msgpack==0.5.6
numpy==1.15.4
oauth2client==4.1.3
pandas==0.23.4
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pyfcm==1.4.5
pymongo==3.7.2
python-dateutil==2.7.5
python-http-client==3.1.0
pytz==2018.7
raven==6.9.0
requests==2.20.1
requests-toolbelt==0.8.0
rsa==4.0
sendgrid==5.6.0
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.24.1
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Note that `pymongo>=2.7.1` is installed as a dependency of `mongoengine`

**Update:**
After removing `bson` and adding `pymongo==3.7.2` to the requiements file, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
     worker.init_process()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
     self.load_wsgi()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
     self.callable = self.load()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
     return self.load_wsgiapp()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
     __import__(module)
   File "/app/slots_tracker_server/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
     from mongoengine import connect
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
     from mongoengine import connection
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mongoengine/connection.py", line 1, in <module>
     from pymongo import MongoClient, ReadPreference, uri_parser
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
     from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 20, in <module>
     from bson.code import Code
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bson/code.py", line 18, in <module>
     from bson.py3compat import abc, string_type, PY3, text_type
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bson.py3compat'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pymongo>=2.7.1 directive overwrites your bson installation

from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver

> Do not install the "bson" package from pypi. PyMongo comes with its
>   own bson package; doing "easy_install bson" installs a third-party
>   package that is incompatible with PyMongo.

assuming you really want to use the 3rd party bson, you'll need to

1. `pip uninstall bson` (removes the overwritten bson that landed via pymongo package)
2. `pip install bson` (reinstalls the py-bson package)

or you could patch the pymongo install to remove the collections.abc line (evidently you don't really need it?), but messing with production packaged code is questionable.

pymongo module
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/py3compat.py#L22-L25

py-bson module you are trying to use.
https://github.com/py-bson/bson/blob/master/bson/py3compat.py#L22-L24

Comment: How should I use the `pymongo bson` module? 
In my `pip freeze` I have `bson==0.5.7` because it's part of my requirements file, but I don't have to use it if `pymonogo` have the same functionality. Also, I'm not using `pymongo` directly, I'm using `mongoengine==0.16.1` and it installs `pymongo`

Comment: I see that I can use `from bson import json_util` but this is not intuitive (and also raise an error in the PyCharm) to use a package that I don't install.

Comment: It should be as easy as removing bson from your requirements.txt and including pymongo which contains a bson package (its painful that mongo doesnt allow this to be seperate).  I did that with your requirements file, opened a python interpreter and ran `import collections.abc as abc` and it worked  without throwing the error feom the question

Comment: I'm running on Heroku so I can't control how the environment is been set up. I run heroku repo:purge_cache -a APP_NAME and redeploy the app from Git and now it seems to be working.

Comment: Hi @shiomiLan just to add to the discussion, I just ran into this problem, which by making the bson install first and then pymongo, solved my heroku deployments. Pretty stange.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem last week. On my PC, the code runs fine. But on Heroku, it fails with the same error.

Maybe it's a little late, but in case more people run into such a problem, I will point out what solved it for me.

First I tried to:

- Change the versions of BSON and PyMongo modules.
- Delete the `.venv` directory.
- Perform other different suggestions I saw on the net.

After none of them worked for me, I tracked the problematic imports (by Heroku CLI) with the command:

```
heroku logs --tails
```

I discovered which imports made, from where, and to which modules, and I imported the same modules in the main app file.

I will explain in more detail.
The problem starts with the import of `json_util` :

```
from bson import json_util
```

If we open the`json_util` file, we will see additional imports and the next problematic import made within it:

```
from bson.py3compat import (PY3, iteritems, integer_types, string_type, text_type)
```

Inside the `bson.py3compat` module, you can find the next imports:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import collections.abc as abc
```

I took all these 3 imports and imported them into the main app directly:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from bson import json_util
from bson.py3compat import PY3 #1
import collections.abc as ABC #2
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod #3

# Init
app = Flask(__name__)
```

These steps have solved my problem and I hope they will help you too.
It may not be the most intelligent solution, but for times of urgency, it is excellent.